# Applying a specific CSS to TinyMCE

Tags: css, tinymce

I'm using `content_css:` and have a script in place that allows me to change the css applied to a TinyMCE component based on a CMS project code.

I found a problem when I have a site that has a colour set as the background and then white for the text.

The TinyMCE looked to start applying the css correctly but when it reached the text the background changed back to being white with black text, but it then goes on to apply some of the styles, this means that my hyperlinks (on this particular site) look to disappear as I have defined the colour as white.

Is there something I can change that will apply the correct background colour in the  tinyMCE tool without affecting the actual outcome of the site's css?

Comment: In all browsers? Have you checked what styles is your hyperlink getting applied?

Comment: have tested in chrome and IE8.  I am appling my style to the base `a` and `a:hover`

Comment: Hard to tell - do you have an example site?

Comment: I think I am on to something, but my css keeps caching. I think it is because I have a background image and colour associated with the html but not the body, so it isnt applying any of the the css to the body tag in  tinyMCE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the css to be applied to the tinyMCE editor, you need to make sure the `body` tag has a `background` and `color` value too, else it will not pull this through and instead use what looks to be a default style.